# User properties in AD not opening (WS 2003)

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003

My Windows 2003 Server has this annoying problem... It happens several times and till now, my only solution, is to reboot the server...

The problem is that when I open AD (dsa.msc) nad try to go to the users properties (right click on users, properties) it just doesn't do anything... it doesn't open the properties window, it doesn't give an error, nothing...it simple doesn't do anything...

do you know if there's some service I can restart so I can see these windows again or do I have to keep rebooting the server?

Answer (score 1):

Active Directory runs in-process with the Local Security Authority (`lsass.exe`) in Windows Server 2003. There's no way to restart it without rebooting.

What you're seeing is definitely odd behavior. I'd be checking out the Directory Service and System Event Logs, as well as attempting to run some simple LDAP queries (using the `dsquery` tool, or the `ldp` tool from the the Windows Support Tools) during one of these "outages" just to see how / if the LDAP server is responding.

This is definitely strange and disturbing behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think the problem is different. I've now found out that I can't open any properties window (for example, I can't open any even on the event viewer), and also if I try to open the start menu, it closes automatically... This all gets fixed after a reboot but after a while it gets back...I'm clueless of what it could be...any thought where I can search/trace the cause for this strange behaviour?

Comment: This misbehavior persists across a logoff/logon, too, then? It also happens if you logon with a different user account? This happens on the local console, over RDP, or both?

Comment: Yes it persists with logoff/logon and on the local console. I haven't tried it with a different user, do you think it could make a difference?

Comment: It's worth checking, at least.